# Cannot setup SSL with Glassfish

Tags: java, ssl, https, glassfish, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to install SSL-certificate into Glassfish 4.1.1.

I've done the following:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /home/user/domain.com.jks -destkeystore /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks

keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore keystore.jks -alias root -file root.crt
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore keystore.jks -alias intermediate1 -file 1_cross_Intermediate.crt
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore keystore.jks -alias intermediate2 -file 2_issuer_Intermediate.crt
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore keystore.jks -alias domain_com -file 3_user_domain.com.crt
```

Then I renamed SSL-reference for http-listener-2 from 's1as' to 'domain_com' at server-config using Administration Console.

And restarted domain via Administration Console and button 'restart'.

After that, I cannot access my application at https://domain.com:8181. Error:

> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

And even cannot access Administration Console at https://domain.com:4848 with

> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Where can I see what happends and how can I properly configure SSL.

One more remark: passwords for keystore and master-password for glassfish **are both default passwords (changeit) and match each other**. I've verified.

Can you provide some clues of where to look?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: In glassfish-logs I'm having the following exceptions:

```
[2016-08-17T10:29:53.142+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.network.config] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _T$
  GRIZZLY0050: SSL support could not be configured!
java.io.IOException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.Error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.$

        at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.ssl.JSSE14SocketFactory.init(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:162)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.SSLConfigurator.initializeSSLContext(SSLConfigurator.java:249)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.SSLConfigurator.configureSSL(SSLConfigurator.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.SSLConfigurator$InternalSSLContextConfigurator.createSSLContext(SSLConfigur$
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:209)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:186)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:293)

[2016-08-17T10:29:53.143+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain] $
  GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:214)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator.createSSLEngine(SSLEngineConfigurator.java:186)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:293)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to insert your certificates in cacerts.jks 
Include root and intermediate certificates in cacerts like this 
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts.jks -alias root -file root.crt 
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts.jks -alias intermediate1 -file 1_cross_Intermediate.crt 
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts.jks -alias intermediate2 -file 2_issuer_Intermediate.crt

Domain certificate not necessary to insert in cacerts.jks

Comment: NOTE: glassfish master password,keystore and domain certificate password should be same.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, still need to work on your keystore. You could use [KSE](http://www.keystore-explorer.org/) to edit the key, much easier to handle certificates.

- Are you sure that the keystore, and the certificate entry, both have the 
  password "changeit"?
- Is the certificate chain right for this certificate entry?

Comment: Thank you for your response! Solved the problem by using letsencrypt certificates. Yes, both passwords were 'changeit' and I did not manage to cope with that problem.